# UIElements does not firing on view highrarchy

Tags: ios, xcode7, swift2

i added two custom view classes and the elements of that class are addede to viewcontroller class but i cannot accecssing 1st element but i can access second element

hear my code

1st class

class TextField: UIView {

```
override init(frame: CGRect) {
    super.init(frame: frame)


    let view=UIView(frame : CGRectMake(8,100,270,47))

    let headerText=UILabel(frame :   CGRectMake(0,0,view.bounds.width,16))
    headerText.text="label"
    headerText.textColor=UIColor.blackColor()
    headerText.textAlignment=NSTextAlignment.Left
    headerText.font = UIFont.systemFontOfSize(13.0)
    headerText.numberOfLines = 0
    view.addSubview(headerText)

    let textField=UITextField(frame : CGRectMake(0,20,view.bounds.width,28))
    textField.borderStyle=UITextBorderStyle.RoundedRect
    textField.userInteractionEnabled=true
    textField.keyboardType=UIKeyboardType.NamePhonePad

    view.addSubview(textField)

    self.addSubview(view)
}

required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
}
```

}

2nd class

protocol  ElementDelegate {

```
func buttonClick(sender:UIButton)
```

}

class ButtonClass: UIView {

```
override init(frame: CGRect) {
    super.init(frame: frame)

    let button=UIButton(frame: CGRectMake(10,50,270,30))
    button.setTitle("Click", forState: UIControlState.Normal)
    button.backgroundColor=UIColor.blueColor()
    button.userInteractionEnabled=true
    button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(button_click(_:)), forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)

    self.addSubview(button)

}

required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
}

func button_click(sender:UIButton){
   delegate.buttonClick(sender)
}
```

}

my viewcontroller class

class ViewController: UIViewController,ElementDelegate {

```
override func viewDidLoad() {

   let screenSize:CGRect=UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds


    let date = TextField(frame: CGRectMake(0,10,screenSize.width,screenSize.height))
    self.view.addSubview(date)

   let element = Button(frame: CGRectMake(0,70,screenSize.width,screenSize.height))
   element.delegate = self
     self.view.addSubview(element)
 }
```

}

when under running i added first textfield view second i added button view but when i click in textbox i cannot accessing it but button is working fine when i remove button textbox working fine why i cannot accessing both one after another

please help me.....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
let date = TextField(frame: CGRectMake(0,10,screenSize.width,screenSize.height))
...
let element = Button(frame: CGRectMake(0,10,screenSize.width,screenSize.height))
```

You've created two subviews with exactly the same frame (size and position). The one you add second will be on top of the other, and will be taking the touch events, even if the button and textfield within them are in different places - a plain `UIView` will still take touch events.

Why are you making a view subclass that just holds another view inside it in a different position? Why not just position the button and textfield directly?

Comment: first of all thanks for the reply i am rendering these textfields,buttons from xml tags to built ui in my view i got those date and button one after another only